# Retrieving digital signature information from a PDF file using Python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, digital-signature

I am looking for a direction on how to retrieve the digital signature information in a PDF (signer details, date of signature, issuer, etc) with Python 2.7. Do I need to use a signature module like django-endesive (not the endesive since I think its , or can I retrieve it while reading a file?

Currently the user adds the signature via an external program, locally, and then uploads the file to the server via the application and encrypts it with pycrypto.

Is it possible to retrieve that information during -say- reading the file before encryption and how can I go about that?

Below is the code I use to encrypt a file:

```
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
  if not os.path.isfile(outFile):
    with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
      outfile.write(filesize)
      outfile.write(IV)
      while True:
       chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
       if len(chunk) == 0:
         break
       elif len(chunk)%16 !=0:
         chunk += ' ' * (16 - (len(chunk)%16))

       outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, I have checked python PDFs libraries such as PyPDF2 and read Adobe Acrobat SDK documentation and still I got nothing. I guess endesive is the way but I am not able to get that info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pyhanko`.

```
pyhanko sign validate --pretty-print test.pdf
```

Or

```
from pyhanko.sign.general import load_cert_from_pemder
from pyhanko_certvalidator import ValidationContext
from pyhanko.pdf_utils.reader import PdfFileReader
from pyhanko.sign.validation import validate_pdf_signature

root_cert = load_cert_from_pemder('path/to/certfile')
vc = ValidationContext(trust_roots=[root_cert])

with open('document.pdf', 'rb') as doc:
    r = PdfFileReader(doc)
    sig = r.embedded_signatures[-1]
    status = validate_pdf_signature(sig, vc)
    print(status.pretty_print_details())
```